# Set an appointment if block then cannot make an appoinment (C#)

Tags: c#, filtering

I want to set an appointment between 10 Nov 2022 12:41 PM (aptStartDate) and 10 Nov 2022 03:41 PM (aptEndDate).

If the datetime of the holiday table is set 09 Nov 2022 12:00 PM (startDate) to 15 Nov 2022 1:00 PM (endDate)
that is

```html
09 Nov 2022 12:00 PM - 09 Nov 2022 1:00 PM
10 Nov 2022 12:00 PM - 10 Nov 2022 1:00 PM
11 Nov 2022 12:00 PM - 11 Nov 2022 1:00 PM
12 Nov 2022 12:00 PM - 12 Nov 2022 1:00 PM
13 Nov 2022 12:00 PM - 13 Nov 2022 1:00 PM
14 Nov 2022 12:00 PM - 14 Nov 2022 1:00 PM
15 Nov 2022 12:00 PM - 15 Nov 2022 1:00 PM
```

May I know how to write a proper condition to find and set an appointment between 10 Nov 2022 12:41 PM (aptStartDate) and 10 Nov 2022 03:41 PM (aptEndDate), if the datetime within in the holiday table is in the appointment, just can't set an appointment.

**Scenario sample variable:**

```
aptStartDate = 10 Nov 2022 12:41 PM
aptEndDate = 10 Nov 2022 03:41 PM
startDate = 09 Nov 2022 12:00 PM
endDate = 15 Nov 2022 1:00 PM

//So this scenario sample cannot make an appointment, because hit the datime between 10 Nov 2022 12:00 PM to 10 Nov 2022 01:00 PM
```

I tried below code is doesn't work

```html
public async Task<OrganizerTimeSlot> CheckDoctorAvailability(DateTime aptStartDate, DateTime aptEndDate, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
        {
            return await RepoHelper.TryCatchAsync("CheckDoctorAvailability", async () =>
            {
                OrganizerTimeSlot orgTimeSlot = new OrganizerTimeSlot();
                DateTime formatAptStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(aptStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
                DateTime formatAptEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(aptEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
                DateTime formatStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
                DateTime formatEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));

                if (formatAptEndDate < formatStartDate || formatAptStartDate > formatEndDate)
                {
                    orgTimeSlot.IsAvailable = true;
                    orgTimeSlot.StartDate = null;
                    orgTimeSlot.StopDate = null;
                }
                else 
                {
                    orgTimeSlot.IsAvailable = false;
                    orgTimeSlot.StartDate = formatStartDate;
                    orgTimeSlot.StopDate = formatEndDate;
                }
                return orgTimeSlot;
            });
        }
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: What is the question? What does not work as you intend and expect?

Comment: if (formatAptEndDate < formatStartDate || formatAptStartDate > formatEndDate)
My condition here got something problem

Comment: And why do you convert DateTimes to String and back?

Comment: _"My condition here got something problem"_ - ok. _What_ problem? We cannot read your mind. Everything we know is what you tell us.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question, or which parts you not understand

Comment: I do not understand what the problem _is_. You write in question: _"So this scenario sample cannot make an appointment, because hit the datime between 10 Nov 2022 12:00 PM to 10 Nov 2022 01:00 PM"_ which is correct. The condition works as intended. If you want different TimeSpans to be checked, you need to create those and check them.

Comment: In other words: if you actually want the 09th-15th- TimeSpan to be split up into daily timespans, you need to actually do that. It won't happen automagically.

Comment: Alright, so I need to separate time and date then write the condition

Comment: Kind of, yes. If your appointment is completely outside, then you can stop. But in this case, it is inside. So you need to take the appointment's date and create the break-TimeSpan => 10th 12PM to 10th 1PM and then check that again with the appointment.

Comment: @Fildor if((formatAptEndDate < formatStartDate || formatAptStartDate > formatEndDate) && (formatAptEndTime < formatStartTime || formatAptStartTime > formatEndTime)) 
Like this condition right?

Comment: You don't have to solve it all in one block. Divide and Conquer.